# Difference between Assert function in cpp and error handling

Tags: c++, assert

I have referred to some sites online and It has made me curious about this function. One site recommended the use of assert as function precondition where it could be used for detecting problems related to manipulation of data during parallel threads. But as people say that assert should be removed during release of the software. But we can detect this problems with a simple if else and exit combo. So I dont get how using assert is any different.

Comment: `assert()` will usually compile to no code in a release build.  [See this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert)

Comment: If you compile with preprocessor definitions `NDEBUG`, the definition for the assert becomes a function that takes a boolean and does nothing.

Comment: preconditions are something you assume to hold, you don't want to test them every time the function is called, unless you are in a debug build, then you use `assert`

Comment: @Mansoor in case of `NDEBUG` the macro will be `#define assert(condition) ((void)0)` so `condition` won't be evaluated in release build. Which is an important difference to `becomes a function that takes a boolean and does nothing`. A reason why you should not have an expression as the condition for `assert()` that has side effects.

Comment: @t.niese Takes does not mean evaluate, merely that if you do not provide it, the macro will complain.

Comment: I use assert (not Assert) to document the contract of my functions. Then, it is the responsibility of the caller to make sure my function is called with correct arguments. I use if() when it is my function responsibility to check for the correctness of the arguments. Having the asserts disabled in release may or may not be wanted, independently. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert

Comment: @Mansoor ok the I read it the wrong way. I read it as that the definition of the macro function (the part after the `#define assert(condition)`) becomes a function that takes a boolean and does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it comes down to there being two (or more) kinds of "errors" that you can encounter in your program:

If you have a text field and ask a user to input a date in "yyyy-mm-dd" format, and the user writes "It is tuesday". Then that is a type of error that you can catch and respond to - and moreover, it is not something that is wrong with the program.

On the other hand, if you have a date picker (displays a calendar and lets the user pick there), then it should *only* be able to return valid dates (and possibly a "user refused to pick" value). If it can return "2020-14-52", then the date picker code is just broken.

If you are concerned that your date picker may be bugged (maybe you are in the process of writing your own), then you can add some `assert(validDate(date))` calls to all the date returns you get from your picker. That way the program will terminate with a big red finger pointing at the failed assert every time the date picker returns an invalid date. This is very valuable during development.

However, once you are satisfied that your date picker is working and only returns valid dates, then all those extra checks are redundant and can be removed. But here the `assert` has another nice feature; if you compile in debug mode then the check stays, but if you compile in release mode then it becomes an empty call that can be optimized out by the compiler.

In short: Error handling is for stuff that can go wrong during execution in a correctly working program. Asserts are for stuff that must not be able to go wrong (and if it does then something is fundamentally broken in the code).

Comment: Something like `assert(validDate(date))` can be problematic. In release build `assert` is `#define assert(condition) ((void)0)`, as of that `validDate(date)` won't be evaluated in release build. If `validDate` has no side effects, it is not problematic, but if it has, then you out of sudden could have different behavior in the release build then you have in the debug build.

Comment: @t.niese Good point. It is a made up example, so that `validateDate` does not actually exist. But it is an important, general point that test and validation code should not have side effects on the rest of the program.